# Haskell: Parsing JSON data into a Map or a list of tuples?

Tags: json, haskell

Is there a way to automatically convert JSON data into Data.Map or just a list of tuples?
Say, if I have:

```
{Name : "Stitch", Age : 3, Friend: "Lilo"}
```

I'd like it to be converted into:

```
fromList [("Name","Stitch"), ("Age",3), ("Friend","Lilo")]
```

.. without defining a Stitch data type.

I am happy to parse integers into strings in the resulting map. I can just read them into integers later.

Comment: What's the data type for the incoming JSON?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `aeson`. See [Decoding a mixed-type object](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.3/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:4) in its documentation's tutorial:

```
>>> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS
>>> :m +Data.Aeson
>>> let foo = BS.pack "{\"Name\" : \"Stitch\", \"Age\" : 3, \"Friend\": \"Lilo\"}"
>>> decode foo :: Maybe Object
Just fromList [("Friend",String "Lilo"),("Name",String "Stitch"),("Age",Number 3.0)]
```

An `Object` is just a `HashMap` from `Text` keys to `Value` values, the `Value` type being a sum type representation of JS values.